# Python kafka module when used with pyspark causes 'ModuleNotFound' error?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am able to submit and run a pyspark script I wrote.

Command to Run the script pyspark_client.py:

```
❯ clear;/opt/spark/bin/pyspark < pyspark_client.py
```

I am also able to run a python-kafka script separately without any issues. This means I have the module installed.

But the issue arises when i combine both the scripts and submit it to pyspark.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from json import dumps
from kafka import KafkaProducer
```

It cannot find the python-kafka module.
The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kafka'
```

All I want to do is write the counts of tweets in each window to a kafka topic. The way I get the topic and count from a window is that I iterate through rows of the the window df.

```
topic,count = row.__getitem__("hashtag").__getitem__("text"),row.__getitem__("count")
```

Minimum reproducable code for error:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from json import dumps
from kafka import KafkaProducer

print("Hello")
```

Version details:

- kafka-python==2.0.2
- pyspark==3.2.1

Comment: Using inbuilt pyspark kafka as suggested and "write" instead of "WriteStream" helped me write batch data to kafka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyspark has its own Kafka support, that doesn't depend on `kafka-python` module. You should remove it, along with the import. You should also be using `spark-submit pyspark_client.py` to run the code, not input redirection into the pyspark interpreter.

Alternatively, assuming you're using tweepy, you don't need Spark to produce data to Kafka

Comment: Thanks for the input. But the pyspark support for kafka allows only to write the pyspark stream to kafka right? But i would want to write just the integer extracted from the dataframe into the kafka topic.

Comment: @VerilogCoder You mentioned twitter - how are you getting a dataframe of tweets? If it is a **pandas** dataframe, then you will need to loop over it, and generate individual JSON messages to send, for example, yes. https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/#kafkaproducer